# Why will this string not convert to float?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Column 'Amount' is a string. I want to change it to float so that I can input these rows into a later calculation.

```
In [1] import pandas as pd

       data = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

       data
```

```
Out [1] 
    ID  Amount          Cost
0   A   9,596,249.09    1000000
1   B   38,385,668.57   50000
2   C   351,740.00      100
3   D   -               23
4   E   178,255.96      999
```

Note the that 'D' has an Amount of ' -   ' rather than zero.

First I clean up the bad data:

```
In [2]
    data['Amount'] = data['Amount'].replace(' -   ', 0)
    data
```

```
Out [2]
    ID  Amount          Cost
0   A   9,596,249.09    1000000
1   B   38,385,668.57   50000
2   C   351,740.00      100
3   D   0               23
4   E   178,255.96      999
```

Then I try to convert to float using 2 methods. Both unsuccessful:

```
In [3]
    pd.Series(data['Amount']).astype(float)
```

```
Out [3]
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: '9,596,249.09'
```

and:

```
In [4]
    pd.to_numeric(data['Amount'])
```

```
Out [4]
    ValueError: Unable to parse string "9,596,249.09" at position 0
```

In my desperation I attempt to loop through the rows:

```
In [5]
    def cleandata(x):
        return float(x)

    data['Amount'] = data['Amount'].apply(cleandata)
```

```
Out [5]
    ValueError: could not convert string to float: '9,596,249.09'
```

Appreciate any advice you could give. I have tried for hours. Thank you.

Comment: `data['Amount'].str.replace(",", "").astype(float)`

Comment: the commas and dots thrown in the mix are the issue. If you're guaranteed that the numbers will appear in the format you've shown here, just replace the commas too before conversion.

Comment: pass param `data = pd.read_csv('input.csv', thousands=',')` so it treats that column correctly, then replace the `-` and it should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a list (y) seems to work.

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
y = list(data["Amount"])
y = [item.replace(" -   " , '0') for item in y]
y = [item.replace("," , '') for item in y]
data["Amount"] = y
data["Amount"] = pd.to_numeric(data['Amount'], errors='coerce')
data['Result'] = data["Amount"] - data["Cost"]
data
```

```
Out [1]:
    ID  Amount      Cost        Result
0   A   9596249.09  1000000     8596249.09
1   B   38385668.57 50000       38335668.57
2   C   351740.00   100         351640.00
3   D   0.00        23         -23.00
4   E   178255.96   999         177256.9
```

There is certainly a better and more pythonic way to write this^ i'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
data = pd.read_csv('input.csv', thousands=',', decimal='.')
```

Comment: Great suggestion. However I receive the same errors and am unable to use Amount in later calculations (Amount minus Cost for example).

Comment: Did you clean up the bad data (the `-`) after reading? what exactly the error you receive?

Comment: Yes, cleaned the bad data then attempt to pass this: data['result'] = data['Amount'] - data['Cost'] 

but receive 2 errors:
 - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
 - TypeError: ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')

Comment: You still have `str` in your data other than `-`. Try: `data['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Amount'], errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of the commas, that way should fix the problem. Try this:

```
data['Amount'] = data['Amount'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(",", "")) # take the commas away
data['Amount'] = data.Amount.astype(float)
```

Comment: You don't need apply, `data['Amount']..str.replace(",", "")` works and is faster.